# What does "as good as'' mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> As good as the English voice cast is, though, it’s a shame that Sucker Punch wasn’t able to find a way to have the performance capture match the Japanese voice acting as well.

What does "as good as'' mean in the sentence?

Comment: As good as O'Hendry's 146 was, it was beaten by Marco Trump's 147.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Still having problem getting my head around it. Is it a set structure?

Comment: It's a ["concessive adverbial clause"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a75e/58ee07c9a16b34644e59c695766060abcf24.pdf) (specifically, "clause of degree") positioned in the initial slot. ***As [adj] as [noun] was, [blah blah]*** means ***even though [noun] was very [adj], it wasn't enough to prevent [blah blah]***.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to analyse grammatically, because it's a blend of two different constructions.

One is complex temporal conjunctions such as *as soon as*, *as quickly as*, and *as long as* (the last of which often loses its temporal meaning and becomes conditional).

The other is the somewhat literary construction *Good as the English voice cast is*, which means "even though the English voice cast is good".

This blend is now quite often heard where only the *Good as ...* would have been used in the past.